# Ruby não acrescenta no final do arquivo

Tags: arquivo, ruby

Preciso adicionar o conteúdo de um array no final de um arquivo, nomeadamente `frames.mcfunction`, porém não é acrescentado no final do arquivo e sim no começo. Como faço para acrescentar no final do arquivo?

**frames.mcfunction:**

```
execute if score frame frames matches 0..0 run function frames/frame_0
execute if score frame frames matches 1..1 run function frames/frame_1
[...]
execute if score frame frames matches 2179..2179 run function frames/frame_2179
execute if score frame frames matches 2180..2180 run function frames/frame_2180
```

**código:**

```rb
# DEFINE NEW LINES
commands = [
  "function end",
  "tellraw @a {\"rawtext\":[{\"text\":\"§b#{'='*20}§r\"}]}",
  "tellraw @a {\"rawtext\":[{\"text\":\"§b=§l§f#{'FINISHED'.center(18)}§r§b=§r\"}]}",
  "tellraw @a {\"rawtext\":[{\"text\":\"§b#{'='*20}§r\"}]}",
  "tellraw @a {\"rawtext\":[{\"text\":\"§f#{'Total:'.ljust(10)}§e#{2181.to_s.rjust(10)}§r\"}]}\n"
]

# APPEND NEW LINES
commands.length.times do |i|
  File.open("frames.mcfunction","a") {|l| l.puts commands[i]}
end
```

**Output:** (arquivo `frames.mcfunction`)

```
function end
tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"§b====================§r"}]}
tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"§b=§l§f     FINISHED     §r§b=§r"}]}
tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"§b====================§r"}]}
tellraw @a {"rawtext":[{"text":"§fTotal:    §e      2181§r"}]}
execute if score frame frames matches 0..0 run function frames/frame_0
execute if score frame frames matches 1..1 run function frames/frame_1
[...]
execute if score frame frames matches 2179..2179 run function frames/frame_2179
execute if score frame frames matches 2180..2180 run function frames/frame_2180
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para adicionar o conteúdo de um array no final de um arquivo, você pode usar o método `File.open()` com o modo de abertura "a" (`append`). Isso permitirá que você adicione novas linhas no final do arquivo, em vez de sobrescrever o conteúdo existente.

```
# Define as novas linhas que serão adicionadas ao arquivo
commands = [
  "function end",
  "tellraw @a {\"rawtext\":[{\"text\":\"§b#{'='*20}§r\"}]}",
  "tellraw @a {\"rawtext\":[{\"text\":\"§b=§l§f#{'FINISHED'.center(18)}§r§b=§r\"}]}",
  "tellraw @a {\"rawtext\":[{\"text\":\"§b#{'='*20}§r\"}]}",
  "tellraw @a {\"rawtext\":[{\"text\":\"§f#{'Total:'.ljust(10)}§e#{2181.to_s.rjust(10)}§r\"}]}\n"
]

# Abre o arquivo em modo de anexo
File.open("frames.mcfunction","a") do |file|
  # Adiciona cada linha do array ao final do arquivo
  commands.each do |line|
    file.puts line
  end
end
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).